# Create Visualforce page that opens up on hyperlink

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce

There is a VF page OpenIncidentsByRep that shows columns having User Names and no. of Incidents of that User, referring from Incident object in a single row. The Number field is an hyperlink. I need to create a VF page (and it's controller class) that will show all incidents assigned to only that particular User whose number field is being clicked on. Please find OpenIncidentsByRep class below. Please guide me here.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class OpenIncidentsByRep{

    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

    public OpenIncidentsByRep()
    {    
        AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT 
        count(Id) Quantity, Rep_Lookup_id__c, Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name RepName, Rep_Lookup_id__r.UPI_Number_abt__c RepUPI  FROM Incident__c
        where Rep_Lookup_id__c <> null
        group by Rep_Lookup_id__c, Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name, Rep_Lookup_id__r.UPI_Number_abt__c];

        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }
    }    

    public class Summary {
        public Integer Quantity { get; private set; }
        public String UPI{ get; private set; }
        public String RepName{ get; private set; }
        public String RepId{get;private set;}

        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
            UPI= (String) ar.get('RepUPI');
            RepName = (String) ar.get('RepName'); 
            RepId = (String) ar.get('Rep_Lookup_id__c');           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming `Incident__c` object has the following fields:**

1. Incident Description (Name)
2. Incident Number (Incident_Number__c)
3. Incident Representative (Rep_Lookup_id__c , given)
4. Incident Status (Status__c)

**Your `controller` would be like this:**

```
public class showRepIncidentsController {
  public List<Incident__c> incidents {get; private set;}
  public String repName {get; private set;}

  public showRepIncidentsController() {
    String repId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('repid');
    if (!string.isBlank(repId)) {
        incidents=[select id,name, Incident_Number__c, Status__c, Incident_Description__c, Rep_Lookup_id__c, Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name from Incident__c where Rep_Lookup_id__c=:repId limit 1000];
        if (incidents!=null && incidents.size()>0) repName = incidents[0].Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name;
    }        
  }  
}
```

**Your VF page (called `showRepIncidents`) would then be like this:**

```
<apex:page controller="showRepIncidentsController" tabStyle="Incident__c">
<apex:pageBlock title="Incidents Assigned to {! repName}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:dataTable value="{! incidents}" var="incident" style="width:100%;">

            <apex:column styleClass="detail" headerValue="Incident Number" headerClass="header">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!incident.id}">{! incident.Incident_Number__c}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column styleClass="detail" headerValue="Status" headerClass="header">
                <apex:outputText >{! incident.Status__c}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>                                

            <apex:column styleClass="detail" headerValue="Incident Description" headerClass="header">
                <apex:outputText >{! incident.Name}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

You didn't post the code of your existing VF page, so the link modification is blindly done. But **assuming you have this code in your existing VF page:**

```
<apex:dataTable value="{! summaries}" var="summary">
  <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
    <apex:outputLink value="/apex/showRepIncidents?repid={! summary.RepId}">{! summary.Quantity}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column headerValue="UPI"></apex:column>
  .
  .
</apex:dataTable>
```

**Then you would modify the related link for the number field like this:**

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/showRepIncidents?repid={! summary.RepId}">{! summary.Quantity}</apex:outputLink>
```

**Take note of** `value="/apex/showRepIncidents?repid={! summary.RepId}"`

1. `/apex/showRepIncidents` points to the new VF page
2. `repid={! summary.RepId}` is the URL parameter to carry the repid value which is being parsed from the controller, which is used to query the related incidents.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a URL parameter to the link called e.g. "userId" that the controller picks up and uses to filter the query:

```
public OpenIncidentsByRep()
{
    Id userId = (Id) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userId');
    AggregateResult[] results = [
            SELECT ...
            FROM Incident__c
            WHERE Rep_Lookup_id__c = :userId
            ...
            ];
```